# Showing $|z|$ is nowhere differentiable using the limit definition.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that the complex valued function, $f(z) = |z|$ is nowhere differentiable using the limit definition:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}.
\end{align*}

This means I cannot use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Here is what I think I should do. For $z\neq 0$ let $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then let $z_n = \frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}$. Then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{|re^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}| - |re^{i\theta}|}{\frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}} &= \lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{|(r+\frac{1}{n})e^{i\theta}| - |re^{i\theta}|}{\frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}}\\
&= \lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{(r+\frac{1}{n}) - r}{\frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}}\\
&= \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}.
\end{align*}
Then if instead I used $z_n = -\frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}$, for large enough $n$, $r-\frac{1}{n} > 0$ and the same steps are justified to get the limit equal $-\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}$.

For $z=0$ then when $z_n = \frac{1}{n}e^{i\theta}$, the limit is just $\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}$ which depends on theta.

Is this good?

Comment: Distinguish two cases. a) $z = 0$. That should be familiar already. b) $z\neq 0$. Choose $\Delta z$ in two ways to get different limits when $\Delta z$ approaches $0$ from two different directions.

Comment: The idea is that $\Delta z$ has a direction of sorts in the complex plane. I would suggest taking the limit as the real part vanishes, and the limit as the imaginary part vanishes, and then show that the two limits are not the same.

Comment: And maybe use the definition that $|z|=\sqrt{zz^*}$

Comment: We know that $f$ is real differentiable for $z\neq0$ so for real $t$, the limit $$\frac{f(z+it)-f(z)}{it}$$ exists and is pure imaginary, whereas the limit $$\frac{f(z+t)-f(z)}{t}$$ is real, hence $f$ must be constant.